# How do I add rows in one table in specific conditions?

Tags: sql, oracle

I work on an Oracle database.
I have a table (it is a join table) but this is how it looks:

```
CustomerID           days_attached  Startdate   enddate              team  
1                     7             01-01-2016   08-01-2016           A
1                     2             09-01-2016   10-01-2016           B
1                     8             01-02-2016   09-02-2016           A 
2                     1             01-02-2017   02-02-2016           C
2                     8             08-05-2017   16-05-2017           C
```

I need to know how long a person is attached to a specific team. A person can be attached to a person for a X amount of days. That person could be in a team.  For instance in this case, how long is a person attached to team A = 7+8 15 days.

How do I get this in a SQL statement? 
Our app only supports SQL not PL/sql .

I expect an output like:

```
CustomerID           days_attached           team  
1                     15                       A
1                     2                        B
2                     9                        C
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: `select customer, team, sum(dayattached) from your_table group by customer, team`

Comment: "add rows" or "select rows"?

Comment: What is the output you expect based on your sample data?

Comment: I expect an output like: 
costumer    daysattached   team
1                       15                a
1                          3                b

Comment: sorry can't work out the html 
<pre> 
costumer                 Days attached                       team
1                                  15                                       a
1                                   2                                        b
</pre>

Comment: Do not add additional information in comments. [edit] your question. To get help on formatting click on the [`?`](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the upper right corner when editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select customer, team, sum(dayattached) from table_name group by customer, team
```

hopefully this will help u

Comment: HI Vibhash, this doesn't work. I need to add up the days attached with the condition to be in team X . So for this exampe i need a row that shows days attached =15

Comment: Apparently my question is not clear enough. Probably that's why people rated my question -2. I am sure this issue is why someone invented PL/SQL, but I have to solve it in SQL. I don't see a simple where clause for this solution. Maybe @APC could give the 'simple where clause' answer? I need to somehow add the days a customer is attached to a team. I've altered my question, maybe it is clearer now?

Comment: Yes your original question wasn't clear. Plus your original comment on this answer says it "doesn't work" which only made it harder to understand what it was you were trying to achieve. But as you have now accepted this answer presumably it does in fact work for you?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear. I think so for now. Still not completely there, but i'll try to make my comments clearer. + now I understand this website a little bit more.